# How to bind ItemsControl's ItemsSource property by using naming conventions in caliburn.micro correctly?

Tags: wpf, naming-conventions, caliburn.micro, itemscontrol

There is an ItemsControl named `Items` in the view and a ViewModel contains a `BindableCollection<T>` property `Items` property, I want them get binding correctly by using the naming conventions mechanism in caliburn.micro, however it dose not works as expected.

When I add `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` in the view explicitly, it works, I am wondering what's the key point  missed when using naming conventions in the ItemsControl?

Comment: `ItemsSource = "Items"` assigns the string `"Items"` to the ItemsSource collection, i.e. the items would be those five characters. It's unclear to which naming convention you are referring. You would usually have a public property named Items in the DataContext object of the view (i.e. the view model) and bind it like `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`.

Comment: I have updated the description.I just found `AddElementConvention<ItemsControl>(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, "DataContext", "Loaded")` in the static constructor of `ConventionManager` class, which I think it will bind the `ItemsSource` property of `ItemsControl` to the property with same name defined in  ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, using the word "Items" as a name for a property, control etc is a bad choice. It's confusing. This is true if someone is maintaining your code or reading a question. You should have considered names for things.

The conventions for caliburn micro are explained here:

https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/conventions

Essentially, a control is examined.

The name is used to look up a property from the datacontext.

If they match then a dependency property of that control will be bound.

Which dependency property is used varies from control to control. Text is the default for TextBox and TextBlock. ItemsSource is the default for an itemscontrol.

Hence the answer to your question is your control name should match the property name.

As they seem to, this is not why your binding is failing.

You also need to provide an instance of that datacontext somehow.

You proved that is happening with your working explicit binding.

The two most likely possible causes are therefore:

Your bootstrapper isn't running the caliburn micro wireup code.

or

Your view isn't provided by the bootstrapper and you've not used viewmodel.bind on it to wire everything up.

or

You've somehow interfered with the default binding conventions.

PS

https://caliburnmicro.com/announcements/stepping-away